# Merging user accounts on Stack Overflow - wrong email address on first one

Tags: discussion, support, merge-accounts

I ended up creating two user accounts for the Stack Overflow sites.

After posting a couple of answers with user id [6070771](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6070771/kiran-kulkarni) (unregistered), I tried signing up.

But when I did not receive the registration email, I came back and noticed that the email address I used all along was incorrect. There was a typo in the email address I submitted.

So I corrected the email address and signed up, but no luck - SO created a new account [6131903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6131903/kiran-kulkarni) for me.

Is there any way to merge these two accounts?

I did a quick search and found this help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.

The problem: Since I do not have access to the initial email address, which is either invalid or belongs to someone else, how can I prove that I am the person who created the two user ids?

I am new here and although I regret losing the little reputation points I earned with the other account, it is okay to start afresh :-)

Nevertheless, I am posting this question to know if there are any other alternative methods to establish the truth of my claim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I merged 'em for ya.

For future reference, you can always visit /contact and let us know you want a merge. We'll ask you a few questions, and - assuming we can verify you own both accounts via a combination of *your additional information* and *our human judgement* - you'll end up with a single account.